# Cocoa Open source XML parser

Tags: xml, cocoa, open-source, rss

I'm looking for an open source XML parser that is easy to integrate with my NSTableView and will handle large amounts of RSS feeds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PubSub Framework ( http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/PubSub/overview/overview.html ). I remember some demo Apple gave at WWDC one year showing it was easy to integrate with NSTableView & NSCollectionView. Though it's not open source.

Comment: awesome!  Is there any sample code and/or tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: Im not aware of any, the guide in this case has really good code. Pretty much all you need to do is add a PSClient ivar to your class, register for PSFeedRefreshingNotification, then call refresh on it and in that method (you did register for check on) check for the feed refreshing and return on YES and when it's NO then check your PSClient for it's entries and do what you need to do to the entries.  The PubSub framework makes it easy to go through the entries after that.

Answer (score 0):

RSS is just a particular kind of XML, so you can use whatever XML parser you like. On OS X, Cocoa itself provides `NSXMLDocument`. On iPhone, you need to find something. http://www.metaobject.com/blog/2009/01/iphone-xml-performance.html would be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm talking about cocoa, not cocoa touch.

And I'm aware of NSXMLDocument, but I don't like using it and I want to see if there's anything out there that you guys have used and liked

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I couldn't read your mind...